# How to use h:selectbooleancheckbox onclick method located in a h:column of a dataTable in order to fill an InputText?

Tags: jsf, datatable

How to use h:selectbooleancheckbox onclick method located in a h:column of a dataTable in order to fill an InputText with the value of one of the columns of that dataTable?

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="formTable">
#{msgs.asunto} 
<h:panelGroup>
<p:inputText value="#{correo.asunto}"
           required="false"
           requiredMessage="#{msgs.formAlta_nombre_requiredMessage}"
           validatorMessage="#{msgs.formAlta_nombre_validatorMessage}"
           id="asunto">
<f:validateLength maximum="20"/>           
</p:inputText>
<h:message for="asunto"/>
</h:panelGroup>

#{msgs.cuerpo} 
<h:panelGroup>
<p:inputText value="#{correo.cuerpo}"
           required="false"
           requiredMessage="#{msgs.formAlta_apellidos_requiredMessage}"
           validatorMessage="#{msgs.formAlta_apellidos_validatorMessage}"
           id="apellidos">

<f:validateLength  maximum="40"/>           
</p:inputText>
<h:message for="cuerpo"/>
</h:panelGroup>

#{msgs.destinatario} 
<h:panelGroup>
<p:inputText required="false"
           id="destinatario">         
</p:inputText>
<h:message for="asunto"/>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="#{msgs.botonEnviar}" 
               action="#{controllerCorreo.salva}">            
 <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form :form-pie"/>
```

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:commandLink rendered="#{controllerContacto.admincomprueba}"
    value="#{msgs.enlaceListadoPrivada}"
    action="#{controllerContacto.listado}" />
<h:commandLink value="#{msgs.enlaceListadoCompartida}"
    action="#{controllerContacto.listadoAgendaCompartida}" />
<h:dataTable var="contacto" value="#{controllerContacto.contactos}"
    border="1">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaNombre}</f:facet>#{contacto.nombre}</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaApellidos}</f:facet>#{contacto.apellidos}</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaDireccion}</f:facet>#{contacto.direccion}</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaCiudad}</f:facet>#{contacto.ciudad}</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaEmail}</f:facet>#{contacto.email}</h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaBaja}</f:facet>
        <h:commandLink action="#{controllerContacto.baja(contacto)}"
            type="submit" value="#{msgs.enlaceBaja}" immediate="true">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form :form-pie" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.tablaEdit}</f:facet>
        <h:commandLink action="#{controllerContacto.edit()}" type="submit"
            value="#{msgs.enlaceEdit}" immediate="true">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form :form-pie" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" value="#{contacto.check}"
            onclick="tobeCompleted" />
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

I want to fill the InputText called "msgs.destinatario" every time I click on the checkbox with the contacto.email value that belongs to that row of the dataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ajax to the checkbox. Run a listener method on it that manipulates the value of the destinatario input field, then rerender the part of the form that has the destinatario value.

That feels easiest, imo.

If you only want it to happen client-side, you could do something with javascript as well. In your onclick-attribute, call a js function that manipulates the input field, e.g: document.getElementById("destinatario").value="new value";